# Flutter : setState() called in constructor: _SharesListState#6c96a(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)

Tags: flutter, constructor, widget, setstate

Error message: This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Really don't understand what it means =/.

```
class SharesHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Header(),
          Expanded(
            child: SharesList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _SharesListState shareListState = _SharesListState();
          final ShareModel shareModel = ShareModel('Embraer', 'EMBR3', 13.50, 15.20);
          shareListState.addShare(shareModel);
        }),
    );
  }
}

class SharesList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<ShareModel> sharesList = [];
  @override
  _SharesListState createState() => _SharesListState();
}

class _SharesListState extends State<SharesList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.sharesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ShareItem(widget.sharesList[index]),
    );
  }

  void addShare(ShareModel shareModel) {
    if (shareModel != null) {
      setState(() {
        widget.sharesList.add(shareModel);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

** I've tried to put "if(this.mounted) to avoid the error, but why isn't the widget mounted?

Comment: Hi Igor, please edit your post to include the unwanted behaviour you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Try with using this: `shareModel != null && ismounted`

It checks if the widget is mounted in the tree, and if that's true, it'll setState.